# How to Use TextureBrush for painting an Image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, gdi+

Using GDI+ I am attempting to make a simple square that consists of an image. This rectangle will be moved. There are a few issues I've been running into. First of all, how to locally refer to the image (it is set to always copy), how to get the image centered in the square, and how to keep the image stationary when the square moves?

```
Bitmap runnerImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"newRunner.bmp", true);//this results in an error without full path

TextureBrush imageBrush = new TextureBrush(runnerImage);

imageBrush.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Clamp;//causes the image to get smaller/larger if movement is tried

Graphics.FillRectangle(imageBrush, displayArea);
```

Without using wrapMode.clamp it defaults to tiling, which looks like the image is tiled and moving the square moves from one image to the next

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When you say stationary, you mean the Image is centered within the square as it moves?

Comment: @MikeAbyss yes, Ideally the square would move around and the image would always be centered inside the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to locally refer to the image (it is set to always copy)

You can add the image to a resource file and then reference that Image from there within the code. (See link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> How to get the image centered in the square, and how to keep the image
>   stationary when the square moves?

This can be achieved using TranslateTransform with displayArea's location
(See link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13fy233f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    TextureBrush imageBrush = new TextureBrush(runnerImage);

    imageBrush.WrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;//causes the image to get smaller/larger if movement is tried

    Rectangle displayArea = new Rectangle(25, 25, 100, 200); //Random values I assigned

    Point xDisplayCenterRelative = new Point(displayArea.Width / 2, displayArea.Height / 2); //Find the relative center location of DisplayArea
    Point xImageCenterRelative = new Point(runnerImage.Width / 2, runnerImage.Height / 2); //Find the relative center location of Image
    Point xOffSetRelative = new Point(xDisplayCenterRelative.X - xImageCenterRelative.X, xDisplayCenterRelative.Y - xImageCenterRelative.Y); //Find the relative offset

    Point xAbsolutePixel = xOffSetRelative + new Size(displayArea.Location); //Find the absolute location

    imageBrush.TranslateTransform(xAbsolutePixel.X, xAbsolutePixel.Y);

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(imageBrush, displayArea);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, displayArea); //I'm using PaintEventArgs graphics
```

Edit: I assumed that Image Size is always <= Square Size